# Efforts in iteration - FizzBuzz

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, fizzbuzz

**EDIT** For what its worth, which admittedley may not be that much. I've done a little test to expand this question.

I've written two functions to enumerate the FizzBuzz "series."

```
private static IEnumerable<string> SimpleFizzBuzz(
        int start = 0,
        int end = int.MaxValue)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(start, end).Select(i =>
        i % 15 == 0 ? "fizzbuzz" :
        i % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" :
        i % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" :
        i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

and,

```
private static IEnumerable<string> OptimizedFizzBuzz(
        int start = 0,
        int end = int.MaxValue)
{
    const int fizz = 3;
    const int buzz = 5;
    const string fizzString = "fizz";
    const string buzzString = "buzz";
    const string fizzBuzzString = fizzString + buzzString;

    var fizzer = start % fizz;
    var buzzer = start % buzz;

    if (fizzer == 0)
    {
        fizzer = fizz;
    }

    if (buzzer == 0)
    {
        buzzer = buzz;
    }

    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        if (buzzer == buzz)
        {
            if (fizzer == fizz)
            {
                yield return fizzBuzzString;
                buzzer = 1;
                fizzer = 1;
                continue;
            }

            yield return buzzString;
            buzzer = 1;
            fizzer++;
            continue;
        }

        if (fizzer == fizz)
        {
            yield return fizzString;
            buzzer++;
            fizzer = 1;
            continue;
        }

        yield return i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        fizzer++;
        buzzer++;
    }
}
```

I've done a little timing, compiled in Release configuration, with optimizations and run from the command line. Over `10^8` iterations, without the overhead of actually reporting each item, I get results that approximate to,

> Simple: 14.5 Seconds
>
> Optimized: 10 Seconds

You'll note that the "optimized" function is faster but more verbose. It's behaviour can be altered simply by changing the constants at its head.

---

Apologies if this seems a little trivial.

Consider this function.

```
using System.Text;

public string FizzBanger(int bound)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < bound; i++)
    {
        String line = String.Empty;
        if (i % 3 == 0) line += "fizz";
        if (i % 5 == 0) line += "buzz";
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) line = i.ToString();
        result.AppendLine(line.ToString());
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

The output will look like

```
1
2
fizz
4
buzz
fizz
7
8
fizz
buzz
11
fizz
13
14
fizzbuzz
16
...
```

Can anybody think of a better way of doing it? Please consider both performance and maintainability.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Sure, I could run the code and examine the output, but I'd rather not.

Comment: “Can anybody think of a better way of doing it?” to be honest? About a million.

Comment: Performance wise... return "12fizz4bangfizz..." :)

Comment: good answer forsvarir I added a parameter to make it more difficult.

Comment: any 1 out of a million would be good.

Comment: @Cody: interview questions!  Though I'd only heard of it as "FizzBuzz" before, not "FizzBang."

Comment: @Dan: Ahh, FizzBuzz! Yes, of course.

Comment: Its only 100 iteration so performance is not the question, next thing is maintain ... i have no idea what its meant to do .. so maintaining this is the real issue

Comment: this is just the FizzBuzz problem, I'm fishing to see what the best way is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
> ```

For a fixed upper bound (100) I wouldn’t bother with this but ok …

> ```
> StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
> ```

But this `StringBuilder` isn’t only redundant, it’s really inefficient. And I don’t even need to benchmark to know this.

> ```
> if (line.Length == 0)
> ```

And this just obscures the logic (this is supposed to implement the “fizzbuzz” problem, right?). Make the logic explicit.

> Please consider both performance and maintainability.

That’s the wrong way round. Maintainability first, performance second (if at all). Your code is actually quite inefficient but that’s irrelevant: there are 100 iterations – performance doesn’t matter at all.

Furthermore, what maintainability overhead does this code have? It’s a toy sample with fixed specs. There are no maintainability issues. I wouldn’t even bother with anything fancy here, Linq solves this automagically:

```
return Enumerable.Range(1, bound - 1).Aggregate("",
    (accu, i) =>
        string.Format("{0}\n{1}", accu,
            i % 15 == 0 ? "fizzbuzz" :
            i % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" :
            i % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" : i.ToString()));
```

But I agree that this may strain readability if one isn’t used to the `Aggregate` function. So make it more explicit:

```
var result = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 1; i < bound; i++)
    result.AppendLine(
        i % 15 == 0 ? "fizzbuzz" :
        i % 3 == 0 ? "fizz" :
        i % 5 == 0 ? "buzz" : i.ToString());
return result.ToString();
```

Everything else is over-engineering.

Comment: Hey, be fair - the outer `StringBuilder` is good practise.  If the whole thing was done with `string + string` a `StringBuilder` would be the first correction.

Comment: I accept the line String Builder is an unnecessary overhead. If the line is not a fizz or bang I want to substitute the ordinal of the line.

Comment: @Dan … perhaps. For 100 items I’m not betting my money on `StringBuilder` being faster and I’d program for simplicity first and start improving once a benchmark says that it’s too slow.

Comment: Tweaked the Aggregation Range and seed to avoid the spurious initial `/n`

Comment: @KonradRudolph looks like you are familiar with FizzBuzz problem :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your code is just an example of what you want to achieve... a proposal to create less StringBuilders:

```
{
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      for (int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
      {
           var rest3 = i % 3;
           var rest5 = i % 5;

           if (rest3 == 0) result.Append("fizz");
           if (rest5 == 0) result.Append("bang");
           if (rest3 != 0 && rest5 != 0)
               result.Append(i);

           result.Append(System.Environment.NewLine);
      }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a good way of optimizing without changing the design. (+1)

Comment: not sure why you use var over bool but it doesn't really matter

Comment: I don’t think introducing variables for things like `x % 3` actually improves readability (nor performance, come to that).

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - Completely agree, I'd never do this in production code. Performace I assume you have less overhead creating useless StringBuilders (which was the main change I proposed). But I'm assuming this is a test or proof of concept he's doing. I also didn't see your reply, otherwise I wouldn't post mine. Nice explanation, +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

What if we make things a bit more difficult?
1) No division or modulo operations allowed;
2) The loop must skip all unnecessary iterations.
Here is the answer:

```
int n3 = 3;
int n5 = 5;
int i = 3;
while (i <= 100)
{
    Console.Write(i.ToString() + " - ");

    if (i == n3)
    {
        Console.Write("fizz");

        n3 = n3 + 3;
    }

    if (i == n5)
    {
        Console.Write("buzz");

        n5 = n5 + 5;
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    i = n3 < n5 ? n3 : n5;
}
```

Comment: I can see advantages to 1) but 2) wasn't part of the question.