# How can i reudce the number if if statments to 2

Tags: c#

how do I reduce the number of if statements in this code

```
for (int i = 1; i < number;i++)
{

    if ( i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " Fizz");
    }
    else if (i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " Buzz");
    }
    else if(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i + " FizzBuzz");
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you [format your code first](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44653219/edit)

Comment: try using `switch` statement instead `if-else`

Comment: There are plenty of example code samples for fizzbuzz solutions, I'd suggest you take a look at them. Also, [codereview.se]

Comment: [Writing FizzBuzz c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11764539/1324033)

Comment: this sounds a lot like an interview question... what have you considered?

Comment: @PaulF c# 7 allows non constant switch conditions

Comment: you can't reduce number of if statements but you can use switch statement instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
for (int i = 1; i < number;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}{2}", i, i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz":"", i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz":"");
}
```

And use no if ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 1; i < number;i++)
{
    string result = i + " ";
    if ( i % 3 == 0)
    {
        result += "Fizz";
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        result += "Buzz";
    }
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This would display for example `1_`, `3 Fizz`, `5 Buzz`, `15 FizzBuzz`.

See the javascript equivalent code snippet below :

```js
var number = 20;
for (var i = 1; i < number;i++)
{
    var result = i + " ";
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        result += "Fizz";
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        result += "Buzz";
    }
    document.write(result+"<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables and the [conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator) can help to make code more readable:

```
for (int i = 1; i < number;i++)
{
    bool isMod3 = i % 3 == 0;
    bool isMod5 = i % 5 == 0;
    string fizz = isMod3 ? "Fizz" : "";
    string buzz = isMod5 ? "Buzz" : "";
    string result = $"{i} {fizz}{buzz}";
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Here's another approach that works with even more values(theoretically umlimited):

```
var modDict = new Dictionary<int, string> { { 3, "Fizz" }, { 5, "Buzz" } };
for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
{
    string text = string.Join("", modDict.Select(kv => i % kv.Key == 0 ? kv.Value : ""));
    Console.WriteLine(i + " " + text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try conditional operators.

```
(i % 3 == 0)
? (i % 5 == 0)
  ? Console.WriteLine(i + " FizzBuzz")
  : Console.WriteLine(i + " Fizz");
: (i % 5 == 0)
  ? Console.WriteLine(i + " Buzz");
  : Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  string output = i % 3 == 0
                    ? ( i % 5 != 0 ? $"{i} Fizz" : $"{i} FizzBuzz" )
                    : i % 5 == 0 && i % 3 != 0
                        ? $"{i} Buzz"
                        : i.ToString();
  Console.WriteLine( output );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string str;
for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
{
    str = i + " ";
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        str += "Fizz";
    if (i % 5 == 0)
        str += "Buzz";

    Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do like below, but it is not good for readability

```
for (int i = 1; i < number; i++)
        {
            var x = i % 3 == 0;
            var y = i % 5 == 0;

            string istr = i.ToString();
            string a = x ? (y ? istr + " FizzBuzz"
                                : istr + " Fizz")
                          : (y ? istr + " Buzz"
                                : istr);
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```