# Linio challenge - Print numbers bw 1 to 100 replace multiples of 3,multiples of 5 & multiples of both 3 & 5 with linio,IT,liianos respectively

Tags: javascript

Write a program that prints all the numbers from 1 to 100. However, for

multiples of 3, instead of the number, print "Linio". For multiples of 5 print

"IT". For numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5, print "Linianos".

But here's the catch: you can use only one **`if`**. No **multiple branches**, **ternary**

**operators or `else`**.

Comment: There is no question in this post. Please fix it

Comment: This is FizzBuzz. You can do this. I believe in you (although without conditionals I can see it being particularly difficult)

Comment: Plenty of examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764539/writing-fizzbuzz/11764613

Comment: yes but please note the conditions to write the code..... Thank you

Comment: This sounds like a task you were given to prove _your_ skills … so why do we have to do all the work for you then?

Comment: sorry, u mistaken me. just wanted to people know about these because i was stuck with these question. it may help someone. thats why i posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var replacer = ["IT", "Linio", "Linianos"];
var accumulator = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) {
    accumulator.push(replacer[Number(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 >= 1) + (Number(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) * 2)]);
    continue;
  }
  accumulator.push(i);
}
console.log(accumulator);
```

here is the solution
for this question.

Answer (score 1):

The modified version of your code without a single **if**

```js
var replacer = ["IT", "Linio", "Linianos"];
var accumulator = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  ((i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0) 
     && accumulator.push(replacer[Number(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 >= 1) + (Number(i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) * 2)])) 
     || accumulator.push(i);
}
console.log(accumulator);
```