# Fizz buzz program wierd output?

Tags: c#

Why does this result in 1 2 Fizz 3 ? Shouldn't it result in 1 2 Fizz?! I'am a little confused with the output of this loop..? Adding else if removes this problem,my question is why?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Output += "Fizz ";
    }
    if (i % 5 == 0)
    {
        ViewBag.Output += "Buzz ";
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Output += i.ToString() + " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Hint, put a breakpoint in there and see what happends.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Homework

Comment: No its not homework assignment I was just really confused why this is the output..

Comment: @Ian Homework questions are not, and have never been off topic (and oh, my, that description is misleading).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I actually thought they were for some reason - I've retracted my close vote. Although giving out answers to homework/interview questions in the long run is obviously counter productive.

Comment: @Ian Absolutely, agreed (which is why there’s a close reason for that). But asking for help on an assignment is okay – only asking for an (almost) complete solution isn’t.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not skipping iteration if first `if` matches. Thus you have `else` part of `i % 5` if block evaluated when current `i` is not divided by 5:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)            
            ViewBag.Output += "Fizz ";             

        if (i % 5 == 0)            
            ViewBag.Output += "Buzz ";

        if ((i % 3 != 0) && (i % 5 != 0))
            ViewBag.Output += i.ToString() + " ";            
    }
```

Alternative solution which uses common `else` block as you have it now:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {          
            ViewBag.Output += "Fizz ";

            if (i % 5 == 0)
                ViewBag.Output += "Buzz ";             
        }
        else if (i % 5 == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Output += "Buzz "
        }
        else // neither divided by 3 nor by 5
        {
           ViewBag.Output += i.ToString() + " ";
        }
    }
```

And one more solution with dictionary, to avoid all this additional if...else checks:

```
var valuesToCheck = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 3, "Fizz" },
    { 5, "Buzz" }
};

for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
{
     bool divisorFound = false;

     foreach(var kvp in valuesToCheck)
     {
         if (i % kvp.Key == 0)
         {
             divisorFound = true;
             ViewBag.Output += kvp.Value + " ";
         }
     }

     if (!divisorFound)
         ViewBag.Output += i + " ";
}
```

Comment: As I recall, a FizzBuzz algorithm should output `"FizzBuzz"` for multiples of `15`, not `"Fizz Buzz"`.

Comment: Depending on taste, anouther way to write the loop in the last example is `for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
      {
        string words = string.Concat(valuesToCheck.Where(x => i % x.Key == 0).Select(x => x.Value));
        ViewBag.Output += (words != "" ? words : i.ToString()) + " ";
      }`. Of course this has the consequence that entries in `valuesToCheck` whose string value ("fizz word") is absent or empty are ignored.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your second `if` is evaluated, no matter the result of the first `if`.

So when i == 3, the first `if` evaluates to `true` and the second to `false`, and therefore the second `if`'s `else` block is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The second `if` is executed, regardless of the preceeding `if` so, the output you experience should be expected.

---

Here's a simple solution to the FizzBuzz problem lifted from a @KonradRudolph [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5661471/659190)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
    ViewBag.Output +=
        i % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz " :
        i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz " :
        i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz " : 
        i.ToString() + " ";
```

or, alternatively.

```
string FizzBuzz(int value, int a = 3, int b = 5)
{
    if value % (a * b) == 0 return "FizzBuzz";
    if value % a == 0 return "Fizz";
    if value % b == 0 return "Buzz";
    return value.ToString();
}
```

used with,

```
viewBag.Output = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, value).Select(FizzBuzz));
```

---

or, going beyond reason

```
IEnumerable<string> Checker<T>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source,
        params KeyValuePair<Predicate<T>, string>>[] checks)
(
    var found = false;
    foreach(var t int source)
    {
        var result =
            string.Concat(checks.Where(c => c.Key(t)).Select(c => c.Value));
        if (result.IsNullOrEmpty())
        {
            yield return t.ToString();
            continue;
        }

        yield return result;
    }
)
```

which could be used like this,

```
ViewBag.Output = string.Join(" ", Enumerable.Range(1, value).Checker(
    new KeyValuePair<Predicate<T>, string>>(i => i % 3 == 0, "Fizz"),
    new KeyValuePair<Predicate<T>, string>>(i => i % 5 == 0, "Buzz"));
```

Comment: +1 Also nice solution if you have several values to check. One improvement I would add is `3 * 5` instead of `15` magic value to show nature of that value

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, applied your advice to the alternative.